# Qual è il tempo verbale giusto?

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood, tenses, conditional-mood

Durante una semplice discussione è uscita fuori questa frase:
"Per vincere (a me oggi) bastava che Pellegrini non facesse (ieri) due assist o un gol".

Subito ho storto il naso e per scherzare ho fatto notare che forse i tempi usati non erano corretti. 
Da questa osservazione è nata una discussione interessante con diverse opinioni a riguardo.

Quindi vi chiedo: è effettivamente corretta questa frase?

Non sarebbe più giusto "Per vincere sarebbe bastato che Pellegrini non avesse fatto due gol"? O al limite "Per vincere bastava che Pellegrini non avesse fatto due gol"?

**Il mio ragionamento** si basa sul fatto che un avvenimento di IERI, o in questo caso il non verificarsi di un'azione, sarebbe servito a me OGGI per vincere.

Fosse stato "Bastava che Pellegrini non segnasse un gol un assist" penso sarebbe stato corretto, in quanto indefinito o riferito tutto a qualcosa passato e quindi contemporanei tra loro.

Grazie

Comment: La lingua italiana come ente a sé è molto più tollerante delle regolette insegnate nelle scuole. Queste due domande e relative risposte sono d'aiuto? [1](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8346/imperfetto-indicativo-al-posto-del-congiuntivo) e [2](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11054/dovevo-vendere-tutte-le-mie-cose-per-comprare-questautomobile-use-of-imperf).

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!!!

Comment: @DaG: Il problema è che quelle domande e le relative risposte coprono il fenomeno dell'uso dell'indicativo imperfetto al posto di altri tempi verbali, ma non l'uso del congiuntivo imperfetto al posto di altri tempi verbali, che è il principale dubbio che espone la domanda per quanto l'ho capita io.

Answer (score 1):

Per scrivere questa risposta mi sono basata sulle spiegazioni e gli esempi che appaiono nel libro che ho usato per preparare l'esame d'italiano di livello C1, cioè, *Nuovo Contatto C1. Corso di lingua e civiltà italiana per stranieri* di R. Bozzone Costa, M. Piantoni, E. Scaramelli e C. Ghezzi.

Tutto dipende del registro in cui stai usando la lingua. La tua frase rientra nel cosiddetto periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà, che corrisponde a quando

> il fatto è sentito dal parlante come impossibile, irrealizzabile (al presente) o irrealizzato (al passato).

Il caso che stiamo analizzando corrisponde a un fatto impossibile perché irrealizzato nel passato, come in questi esempi:

> - Se avessi studiato, avresti passato l'esame.
> - Se avessi vinto il concorso, avrei ricevuto una borsa di studio.

(Cerco di riscrivere questo ultimo esempio in  modo che sia più simile alla frase della domanda: "Sarebbe bastato che avessi vinto il concorso e avrei ricevuto una borsa di studio". E ancora si assomiglia di più se scrivo: "Sarebbe bastato che avessi vinto il concorso per ricevere una borsa di studio".)

Come si vede in questi esempi, in un registro formale, i tempi verbali da usare sono il congiuntivo trapassato per la condizione (protasi) e il condizionale passato per la conseguenza (apodosi). Quindi, in un registro formale, si dovrebbe dire

> Se Pellegrini non avesse fatto due gol avremmo vinto

o, formulato nel modo che hai scritto nella domanda,

> Per vincere sarebbe bastato che Pellegrini non avesse fatto due gol.

Tuttavia, il libro che ho menzionato spiega anche quanto segue:

> Nel registro colloquiale nel periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà per parlare di fatti del passato si tende a usare l'imperfetto.

Così, in un registro informale, invece della frase *Se fossi venuto a casa mia avremmo mangiato una pizza insieme*, possiamo trovare:

> - Se fossi venuto a casa mia mangiavamo una pizza insieme.
> - Se venivi a casa mia avremmo mangiato una pizza insieme.
> - Se venivi a casa mia mangiavamo una pizza insieme.

È quello che accade nella frase

> Per vincere bastava che Pellegrini non avesse fatto due gol

in cui si usa l'imperfetto indicativo ("bastava") al posto del condizionale passato ("sarebbe bastato"). E, come negli esempi del libro, si potrebbe anche usare l'indicativo imperfetto al posto del congiuntivo trapassato (sempre in un registro informale):

> Per vincere bastava che Pellegrini non faceva due gol.

Il fatto curioso è che nella frase che hai sentito ("Per vincere bastava che Pellegrini non facesse due gol") si è usato il congiuntivo imperfetto ("non facesse") invece dell'indicativo imperfetto ("non faceva"). Non ho mai trovato nessuna fonte autorevole che riporti come caratteristico di nessuna "varietà substandard" (corrispondente a un registro colloquiale) questo uso del congiuntivo imperfetto per una protasi riferente a un fatto irrealizzato nel passato. Anzi, il mio libro spiega che il congiuntivo imperfetto nella protasi

> è usato quando l'ipotesi è valida anche al presente (o sempre): *Se **fosse** una persona generosa ti **avrebbe aiutato***

in uno dei cosiddetti periodi ipotetici di tipo misto. In un registro informale, questa ultima frase penso si possa rendere "Se fosse una persona generosa ti aiutava", come in questo esempio tratto dall'articolo ["Costrutti condizionali in italiano antico"](https://www.academia.edu/8672222/Costrutti_condizionali_in_italiano_antico), di Gianluca Colella:

> Ancora no·lla voleva se non avesse biondi i cavelli (*Reggimento de’ principi* XVI, XXIII, 4: 382).

Come la frase che ha motivato la domanda, questi esempi hanno la protasi espressa col congiuntivo imperfetto e l'apodosi con l'indicativo imperfetto, ma, a differenza del caso della domanda, "essere una persona generosa" o "non avere i capelli biondi" sono ipotesi che si ritengono anche valide nel presente. Quindi, in questo senso, sono d'accordo con il ragionamento che hai fatto nel tuo post.

Accade, però, lo stesso con la frase "Bastava che Pellegrini non segnasse un gol un assist": se "non segnare un gol assist" è un'ipotesi che non si è realizzata nel passato, cioè, un fatto che non è accaduto poiché quello che veramente successe fu che Pellegrini segnò un gol assist, in italiano standard questa frase dovrebbe essere

> Sarebbe bastato che Pellegrini non avesse segnato un gol assist

che, nel parlato colloquiale, si potrebbe rendere

> Bastava che Pellegrini non avesse segnato un gol assist

o persino

> Bastava che Pellegrini non segnava un gol assist.

Infine, in questa [altra risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8347) puoi leggere un riassunto su quello che dicono diversi studiosi su questo fenomeno.

Comment: Capisco che in questa risposta ci sia un salto nel vuoto nel passo di "Se avessi vinto il concorso, avrei ricevuto una borsa di studio" a "Sarebbe bastato che avessi vinto il concorso e avrei ricevuto una borsa di studio" o "Sarebbe bastato che avessi vinto il concorso per ricevere una borsa di studio" (si veda questa [domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11638/)).

Comment: Si trova qualche informazione in più su questo uso colloquiale dell'imperfetto indicativo su [questo corso per lo studio dell'italiano colloquiale](https://books.google.es/books?id=07fj5d_l3r4C&pg=PA42). Mi sembra particolarmente interessante l'esercizio che si trova alla fine della pagina 46 in cui si chiede di trasformare la frase "Sarebbe bastato che me lo avessi detto..." usando l'imperfetto indicativo al posto del condizionale passato e del congiuntivo trapassato, corrispondente al periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà di registro colloquiale. Si tratta di un esempio simile a quello della doman

Answer (score 0):

Penso tu abbia ragione anche perché la prima frase lascia pensare a due circostanze che avvengono contemporaneamente e non a distanza di tempo. Ammettendo che la forma grammaticale non sia scorretta certamente non è esplicativa.

A parte il fatto che a qualcuno che è esterno al contesto - come il sottoscritto - il tutto rimane molto oscuro. Di che si parla in effetti? Di due tipi di vittoria differenti suppongo. Tipo la partita ieri ed il campionato oggi... oppure di una partita iniziata ieri e continuata oggi? Mistero!
Non si capisce il nesso tra la vittoria (o solo il vantaggio?) di quelli ieri e la non vittoria di questi oggi.
È una di quelle situazioni in cui chi condivide lo stesso contesto può capire correttamente la frase ma chi è al di fuori di quel contesto e quegli eventi non può capire.

Dulcis in fundo: complimenti al Pellegrini, anche se non si capisce se ha segnato due gol e ha fatto un assist (perché l'assist non si segna ma si fa!) oppure se ha segnato due gol senza fare assist oppure se ha fatto un gol ed un assist!
Comunque siano andate le cose la squadra non mi pare molto ferrata in Italiano :)

Comment: Si parlava chiaramente di fantacalcio https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantacalcio