# Come posso spiegare la struttura di queste frasi?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, sentences, tenses, conjunctions, conditional-mood

Sulla pagina 46 di [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=07fj5d_l3r4C&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q=%22sarebbe%20bastato%20che%22&f=false) ho trovato la frase

> **Sarebbe bastato** che me lo **avessi detto** prima, e te l'**avrei portata** in facoltà.

La frase appare nel contesto di un esercizio per imparare certi fenomeni tipici dell'italiano colloquiale, in cui si richiede di trasformare all'imperfetto indicativo le forme verbali evidenziate quando possibile (in un registro colloquiale). Si chiede anche di indicare per ogni forma trasformata quale funzione comunicativa svolge nel discorso tra quelle di questo elenco:

> - esprimere un desiderio in modo cortese;
> - esprimere l'intenzione di fare qualcosa o il motivo per cui la si fa;
> - fare una richiesta, una domanda o un'affermazione minimizzandone il contenuto, generalmente per ragioni di cortesia e buona educazione;
> - esprimere un'ipotesi nel passato
>     (periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà);
> - esprimere un'opinione riferita a una situazione o evento passato;
> - riportare un discorso indiretto nel passato.

Infatti, l'esempio di uso dell'imperfetto indicativo nel periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà che fa questo libro è

> Se lo sapevo, la portavo

al posto di "Se l'avessi saputo, l'avrei portata", quindi è chiaro che si riferisce all'uso per esprimere l'ipotesi e anche la conseguenza non avvenuta.

Si tratta di una frase che assomiglia a quella che ha motivato  [quest'altra domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11324/).

Nella mia risposta a quella domanda ho scritto che questa frase  rientra nel cosiddetto periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà. Anzi, non esattamente questa frase, ma altre frasi con una struttura simile come, per esempio, questa

> Sarebbe bastato che avessi vinto il concorso e avrei ricevuto una borsa di studio

o questa

> Sarebbe bastato che avessi vinto il concorso per ricevere una borsa di studio

o quella che ha motivato l'altra domanda (perlomeno in una delle versioni proposte dall'OP).

Tuttavia, capisco che questa affermazione sia una sorta di "salto nel vuoto" poiché la frase non ha la struttura più tipica del periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà riferito a fatti non realizzati nel passato, cioè, "se" + congiuntivo trapassato nella proposizione secondaria (protasi) e condizionale passato nella proposizione principale (apodosi), come in questo esempio:

> Se avessi vinto il concorso, avrei ricevuto una borsa di studio.

Le frasi in questione hanno una struttura più complessa: c'è una proposizione subordinata soggettiva introdotta da "bastare che" (con "bastare" al condizionale passato, cosa che dà l'idea di fatto non accaduto); questa subordinata sembra esprimere una condizione non realizzata nel passato; il verbo "bastare" sembra avere il ruolo di introdurre questa condizione;  c'è una proposizione coordinata oppure un infinito introdotto da una preposizione che sembrano esprimere una sorta di apodosi, cioè un'ipotetica conseguenza della condizione che non è avvenuta.

Tuttavia, continuo a credere che queste frasi abbiano a che vedere col periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà riferito a fatti irrealizzati nel passato (fatto anche motivato dall'esercizio che vi ho spiegato sopra). Non so, però, come ragionarlo. Qualcuno di voi mi potrebbe aiutare a fare chiarezza su  questa questione?

Comment: Interessante. M'ero posto di recente un problema similissimo a proposito della famosa massima attribuita ai gesuiti “Datemi un bambino fino all’età di sette anni e io vi darò l’uomo” che, volendo, si può riformulare in forma ipotetica (“se mi date...”).

Comment: Comunque: non trovo una risposta specifica, ma Serianni, parlando delle proposizioni ipotetiche (XIV, 145-171) menziona più volte la possibilità di costruirle in modi diversi dal classico “se X, (allora) Y”. Per esempio, in 148, “occorrerebbero pagine e pagine per elencare tutte le opere in cui compare almeno un gatto”, e di nuovo più avanti.

Comment: Sì, @DaG, questo l'avevo già visto: ma non trovo nessuna spiegazione per frasi simili a quelle della domanda.

Comment: Già. Ora che mi viene in mente, ci rientra il classico “Datemi un punto d'appoggio e vi solleverò il mondo”. Sono tutte situazioni in cui la forma è coordinata, ma il significato è chiaramente subordinato. E nel tuo esempio questo significato è ulteriormente rafforzato dall'uso del condizionale e del congiuntivo.

Comment: Comunque almeno “Sarebbe bastato che avessi vinto il concorso per ricevere...” ha la stessa struttura di “occorrerebbero pagine e pagine per elencare...”.

Comment: @DaG: Tuttavia l'esempio del numero 148 che hai menzionato ha una preposizione + infinito per esprimere la protasi, non l'apodosi.

Comment: Giusto, @Charo, grazie per la precisazione.